# How to open a file and have the contents be the output of an executed command?

Tags: file, unix, random

For example:

When **open/read** `/var/command_result.txt` would have its contents be the results of executing `sysctl -x -B 16 kern.arandom.`

So each time `/var/command_result.txt` is **open/read**, the content is a **different random number**.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there's a good way of doing this. Is there a reason a simple script is unacceptable?

Comment: `ln -s /dev/urandom /var/command_result.txt` maybe?  Though that's an odd place to put the link, and it doesn't produce text.

Comment: @John Moon, re: simple script unacceptable; Sometimes we need to accommodate things beyond our control.  Need the contents of the file to be a different random 32 digit (16 octet) hex number each time it is opened/read.

Comment: Could tell us what platform your on? This is a BSD or Unix, right? There might be a way to create a character device file (hopefully without writing a full-blown module) that behaves this way, then you could link `/var/command_result.txt` to that device file.

Comment: @John Moon, FreeBSD 11.1

Answer (score 0):

Make `/var/command_result.txt` a named pipe and have a process that opens and writes to it repeatedly? That won't work well if you need a concurrent processes reading the file, but if it is just for sequential testing or something, no problem.

```
$ mknod  /tmp/command_result.txt p
$ perl -we '$a=0;
   while(1){
     open(STDOUT,">","/tmp/command_result.txt");
     print "$a\n";
     $a++;
   }' &
[1] 31811
$ head -1 /tmp/command_result.txt
0
$ head -1 /tmp/command_result.txt
810
$ head -1 /tmp/command_result.txt
2431
$ cat /tmp/command_result.txt | head -1
3397
```

As you can see, `head` reads more than one line before outputting the results. When I ran the head commands very rapidly after one another I wound up with broken pipe errors on the perl side. A trap could fix that.